# Aid or Interfere roll+Bond... How much variation is there with bond bonuses?

Tags: dungeon-world

The **Aid or Interfere** move calls for a **roll+Bonds**.  I read that and my first thought was the roll adjustment value is either 0 for no bond, or +1 for having a bond.

But now I'm wondering if there are any other possibilities. Can characters have more than one bond with a character at the same time?  Is there some way to have bonds give negative values for the Bond modifier, or higher valued bonds?

Or, was my first thought correct?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The modifier is the number of bonds with that character.

> *Dungeon World, page 54*
>
> You can use the same character for more than one statement.
>
> When a move has you roll+Bond you’ll count the number of bonds you have with the character in question and add that to the roll.

There aren't any bonds worth anything other than one, but you could add some custom moves to change that. For example, I could imagine a curse that gives -1 bond.

Comment: And only one bond per person, at one time, right?

Comment: You can have multiple Bonds with one person. See the same page, first paragraph, last sentence. (p. 54 in the PDF with cover.)